# Sorting an Integer type Array in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Cannot use `Arrays.sort()` for `Integer` type array if it has null elements. Unlike `int` type array, `null` values are not assigned to 0.
How to sort the `Integer` type array if it has a `null` element?

```
Integer[] arr=new Integer[4] {6,7,null,null};
```

I want to sort this `arr` array variable.

The error is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Comparable.compareTo(Object)" because "a[runHi]" is null
    at java.base/java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:320)
    at java.base/java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:188)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1040)
    at Example.medicinePriceForGivenDisease(Example.java:41)
    at Example.main(Example.java:21)
```

Comment: Of course you can, the `void sort(Object[] a)` overload will handle that.

Comment: If some elements in the Integer array are null, we get error. But if use int array, the null elements are ignored and the array is sorted. Compiler is not ignoring null values if it is Integer type array

Comment: Please give me a solution. In Integer array, null elements are not assigned to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Integer` is a `Comparable`, you can use the overloaded [`Arrays.sort(Object[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)). I.e.:

```java
Integer[] arr = new Integer[4]; //not "int"
// fill in some data in arr
Arrays.sort(arr);
```

**EDIT:**
To address the statement regarding `null`s in the comments, indeed, the natural ordering handled by `Arrays.sort(Object[])` will not handle `null`s (since they have no natural order). You could, however, use a custom `Comparator`. E.g., you could arbitrarily decide to move all the `null`s to the end of the array:

```java
Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

Comment: If some elements in the Integer array are null, we get error. But if use int array, the null elements are ignored and the array is sorted. Compiler is not ignoring null values if it is Integer type array

Comment: @JaisuriyaR an `int[]` can't have `null`s in it. Indeed, `Arrays.sort(Object[])` won't handle `null`s, but you can handle them with a custom `Comparator`. See my edited answer.

Comment: It makes the every element as null.

Comment: @JaisuriyaR that's not true. See, e.g., this demo: https://ideone.com/0OEv1v

Answer (score 1):

The `java.util.Arrays` class has all required methods for sorting, including `sort(Object[] a)`. Since `Integer` is an object, it will do nicely:

```java
Integer[] arr = new Integer[] { 32, 12, 9, 77 };
Arrays.sort(arr);
// Array sorted it
```

Comment: If some elements in the Integer array are null, we get error. But if use int array, the null elements are ignored and the array is sorted. Compiler is not ignoring null values if it is Integer type array

Comment: Did you check the JavaDocs? Elements are compared in pairs: if one of them is null, it will throw. A primitive type, such as int, cannot be null.

Answer (score 0):

The single parameter `Arrays.sort(Object[])` sorts elements that must implement the `Comparable` interface using the `compareTo` method. Basically it calls  `e1.compareTo(e2)` for elements of the array. This will throw an Exception if either `e1` or `e2` is null.

Solution: use the 2-parameter `Arrays.sort(T[], Comparator<? super t)` and provide a `Comparator` that is able to compare 2 elements even if one or both are null.

Very simple example (compares `null` as being `0`):

```java
var comparator = Comparator.comparingInt((Integer n) -> n==null ? 0 : n.intValue());
Arrays.sort(arr, comparator);
```

A class implementing `Comparator` can also be used for more *complex* ordering:

```java
class MyComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
    @Overwrite
    public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
        if (a == null && b == 0) return 0;
        if (a == null) return -1;
        ...  // must be implemented
    }
}


Arrays.sort(arr, new MyComparator());
```

<sup>no IDE was used or hurt while composing this post; included code is meant only as idea how to solve the problem - it is incomplete, eventually wrong or even contain compilation errors</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> sortedArray = Arrays.stream(arr)
                              .filter(x -> x != null)
                              .sorted().toList();
```